# On the slideshow how can i place the arrows on each side of the slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

[image]  The arrows end up on the bottom. Ive tried using margin to move them up but no luck. What can I add to the code so the arrows are on opposite sides? I used w3 for the code but on their example the arrows are on opposite sides. How can I go about doing that?

[W3 code](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self)

```js
/* Slide Show */
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n >= x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/15456887b7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTU3DPk4gCVZ0g40k0xiOjiwcqGY9MJkY4quA&usqp=CAU" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="auction.html">Auction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="proceedings.html">Proceedings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="menu-icon"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/f6/d7/91/b0/c4/a8/41/a1/a4/da/02/38/c8/de/dd/6c/f6d791b0-c4a8-41a1-a4da-0238c8dedd6c-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/55/85/98/b0/60/4b/44/d8/90/83/15/56/03/e0/7b/57/558598b0-604b-44d8-9083-155603e07b57-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/71/e2/4d/a2/cb/10/42/99/a7/94/b2/50/2e/96/72/33/71e24da2-cb10-4299-a794-b2502e967233-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/26/77/14/f7/22/ff/40/99/83/8d/01/1b/ae/93/1d/3b/267714f7-22ff-4099-838d-011bae931d3b-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/3a/e9/36/2c/d3/08/4e/6b/bd/e6/06/7b/2a/22/89/a1/3ae9362c-d308-4e6b-bde6-067b2a2289a1-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/eb/f2/fc/2a/3f/3d/41/87/88/36/bc/17/68/d6/14/3d/ebf2fc2a-3f3d-4187-8836-bc1768d6143d-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/aa/8e/9c/02/aa/1d/48/f4/82/a1/63/f1/fa/c8/bb/52/aa8e9c02-aa1d-48f4-82a1-63f1fac8bb52-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:25%">
      
        <button class="buttonleft" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
      </div>
      <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by arrows in opposite side? It should be inside the image?

Comment: the arrows to move on to the next picture. I added a picture to the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only missed to link your stylesheet 'index.css'. I just put back the link to *w3.css*, fixed the missing *buttonleft* class, and changed the width of each image back to 100% it worked.

If you want to put some margin or resize the images you need to edit the element (div) that contains them.

Probably you need to edit the classes *w3_content* and/or *w3-display-container*.

```js
/* Slide Show */
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n >= x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/15456887b7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTU3DPk4gCVZ0g40k0xiOjiwcqGY9MJkY4quA&usqp=CAU" class="logo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="auction.html">Auction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="proceedings.html">Proceedings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="menu-icon"></i>
        </div>
</div>

    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/f6/d7/91/b0/c4/a8/41/a1/a4/da/02/38/c8/de/dd/6c/f6d791b0-c4a8-41a1-a4da-0238c8dedd6c-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/55/85/98/b0/60/4b/44/d8/90/83/15/56/03/e0/7b/57/558598b0-604b-44d8-9083-155603e07b57-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/71/e2/4d/a2/cb/10/42/99/a7/94/b2/50/2e/96/72/33/71e24da2-cb10-4299-a794-b2502e967233-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/26/77/14/f7/22/ff/40/99/83/8d/01/1b/ae/93/1d/3b/267714f7-22ff-4099-838d-011bae931d3b-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/3a/e9/36/2c/d3/08/4e/6b/bd/e6/06/7b/2a/22/89/a1/3ae9362c-d308-4e6b-bde6-067b2a2289a1-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/eb/f2/fc/2a/3f/3d/41/87/88/36/bc/17/68/d6/14/3d/ebf2fc2a-3f3d-4187-8836-bc1768d6143d-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://d1yb6h7rvkcay2.cloudfront.net/aa/8e/9c/02/aa/1d/48/f4/82/a1/63/f1/fa/c8/bb/52/aa8e9c02-aa1d-48f4-82a1-63f1fac8bb52-large::r:0.jpg" style="width:100%">
      
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
      </div>
      <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

But if you want to work with slides/carousel I highly recommend to see [bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/) or [tiny-slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider), because they make your work easier and the result is pretty and responsive, but there are many more other plugins/tools to work with.

Comment: I used bootstrap carousel. and It is much easier. The only problem i have now is that there are 2 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> How do I make the rest of that page only use index.css instead of the other

Comment: Usually there are several stylesheet links in a webpage, like bootstrap, fontawesome, Google Fonts, etc. It's not recommend to put in one file only, because of performance, organization for example. But you can merge the content of both and create a single file. Then you can call your classes first and put an !important ; mark at the end to be applied instead of bootstrap ones.

Comment: can you show me a sample code? heres my full code:https://github.com/Orelso/Project--Website-finnspeed